# Add UIView Above All Section in UITableView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

i am not talking about a section i want put a uiview on the above of every section

This is the layout

[image]

here Menu and LeftOver are uiView 
Staters and new are sections

Comment: what kind of view? Is it the line? If you want to put it on every section then why don't you make it part of the section view?

Comment: Its menu label and plus button on top of section

Comment: Check the laout image

Comment: Make menu and plus button as cell and drop down as section footer

Comment: You have two options 1) is Add uitableviewheader 2) is add UIView first and add table view to your UIViewController.

Comment: no this is not solution

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a section header. You can easily configure your own custom view by implementing the `UITableViewDataSource` method

For example:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = UIView()
    // configure view, note the method gives you the section to help this process
    return headerView
}
```

you may also want to implement this function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 50 // or whatever it is
}
```

Do keep in mind that header are sticky be default

in the past I've gotten around this fairly easily doing something like this:

```
    let dummyViewHeight = CGFloat(49) // height of header (set in storyboard)
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tableView.bounds.size.width, height: dummyViewHeight))
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -dummyViewHeight, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

which basically just makes the table header "stick" to this inset on top of the table. (unless you really do want it hovering over the section at the top)

#### Edit:

Given the OP considers this "not satisfying" I'm like 99% confident when I say the ONLY other reasonable option (if you don't wan't to use section header or footer views) is to then make a new `UITableViewCell` subclass. Then that new subclass would appears at the top of each section.

So in the `cellForIndexPath:` method you'd check if `indexPath.row == 0`and if so dequeue a cell with a different identifier. That way the header just becomes a cell that is built differently.

If you're doing it programmatically just be sure to register that cell (`tableView.register(MyNewHeaderCellSubclass.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyNewHeaderCellSubclass")`) or otherwise go to the table view on the storyboard and toggle the option for two types of dynamic cell classes.

The section header is exactly what this use case is for however. I cant think of any other solution without just abandoning `UITableView` completely which I think would be a big mistake. Good luck to you otherwise if so.

Comment: But this will become a sction i want a view on top of section

Comment: Also check the layout image

Comment: Yep, this creates a special view that goes on top of a section. In this method you'd create your view that has the plus button and line or whatever and then the cells will fill in normally before. if you return nil in this function it won't add a header.

Comment: if you want to just test to see where this would go, copy and paste my implementation and just simply add `headerView.backgroundColor = .red` to my code and you'll see, in red, where that view would go

Comment: replied to your not satisfying comment with probably your only other option then.

Comment: @ZainAnjum Expanding upon @gadu's proposed solution, what you could do is create an IBDesignable UIView and for each button, in `viewForHeaderInSection`, assign a tag to the button's from `viewForHeaderInSection's` `section` (it'd look something like `plusButton.tag = section`. Then, you could tie a target to it (`plusButton.addTarget<blah blah>` and create a method to do whatever you want to do with the button. You'd just pull the tag off the sender to know what section it came from. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8k9E1gQ_qg

Comment: View is hide with scrolling issue